# Unique IDs inside loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How to give different id to each item in `@for` loop So I can use that unique ID in `jQuery` to retrieve the value?

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < searchList.Count;i++ )
 {
     <label for="one"><input type="checkbox" id="one"/>@searchList[i]</label>
 }
```

Comment: Q: Why aren't you using `Html.LabelFor` and `Html.CheckBoxFor`?

Answer (score 1):

You can append the `i` to the `id="checkbox@i"` to make unique ids.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < searchList.Count;i++ )
{
    <label for="checkbox@i"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox@i" value="@searchList[i]"/>@searchList[i]</label>
}
```

**Note:** The`value="@searchList[i]"` attribute has been forgotten, please add it for a correct functionality.

---

If you want to generate the code that query the ids with `jQuery`, you can make another `for` like below and to make use of `<text>` tag to generate the script.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < searchList.Count;i++ )
{
    <text>
    $("#checkbox@i").click(function () { 
        // logic
    });
    </text>
}
```

Comment: My id is checkbox@i....Should my jquery be                                                               $("#checkbox@i").click(function () {
        var currentChk = $(this);
        var propCheck = currentChk.prop("checked");
        if (propCheck) {
            var valChk = $("#checkbox@i").val();
            alert(valChk);
        }      
    });

Comment: What should I use in jquery to retrieve individual values?

Comment: What you mean by retrieve individual values?

Comment: SearchList contains: Apple, Ball, Cat...So inside @for loop @searchList[0] will be "Apple", @searchList[1] will be "Ball" ..How do I retrieve these individual values using jquery?...var valChk = $("#checkbox@i").val(); alert(valChk);  is not helping...

Comment: @MichaelPhilips It's not working because we forgot to add `value="@searchList[i]"` attribute to `input`, see my code again.

Answer (score 1):

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < searchList.Count;i++ )
 {
     <label for="one"><input type="checkbox" id="one_@i"/>@searchList[i]</label>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append the for loop index `i` in id attribute:

```
<label for="one"><input type="checkbox" id="one@i"/>@searchList[i]</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < searchList.Count;i++ )
{
    <label for="one@i"><input type="checkbox" id="one@i"/>@searchList[i]</label>
}
```